# Animated menu fades in and drops to position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create my first animated menu.

Here's an image of what i'm trying to achieve

[image]

The arrows are to show you that I want the names dropping down and fading in when the menu button is clicked. I also want the menu to spread out across the page evenly.

I've started to create a fiddle but i'm getting no where fast

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/dz0cee5L/21/

Here's the css

```
.button-container {
    width:100%;
}
.button {
    padding: 7px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    border: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navcontainer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
#navcontainer ul li { 
    display: inline; 
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #dbd5d1;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b93037;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS transition with `opacity` and `top`.

The menu should be `position: absolute` so it doesn't move the content, and then in can be hidden with `top: 100%` and `opacity: 0`, as well as `transition: opacity 1s, top 1s` for the animation. Then use jQuery to toggle the showing class.

CSS:

```
#navcontainer {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    transition: opacity 1s, top 1s;
}
#navcontainer.showing {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("#navcontainer").toggleClass("showing");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/dz0cee5L/23/)